# php stripos if page ==

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, stripos

I have the script as below:

```
<li><p class="navbar-text"><a href="/" <?php if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/') !== false) {echo 'class="active"';} ?>>Forside</a></p></li>
<li><p class="navbar-text"><a href="/medlemmer" <?php if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/medlemmer') !== false) {echo 'class="active"';} ?>>Medlemmer</a></p></li>
<li><p class="navbar-text"><a href="/butik">Ansøg</a></p></li>
<li><p class="navbar-text"><a href="/" style="color:white;">Køb</a></p></li>
```

Im using Bootstrap and I have this code in a seperate file, i get from

```
<?php
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $path .= "/header.php";
   include_once($path);
?>
```

The `<?php if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/') !== false) {echo 'class="active"';} ?>` annoys me. All the other pages does as they should, but this "/" slash just takes every page on the server.

I could do /index, but that would look awful in the address bar.

What can I do to have something echoing ONLY on the front-side (index.php)?

Comment: Not entirely following. Can you please be more specific with your issue (not annoyances). Nice name, btw.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not specific enough. I have a class called active, that underlines stuff when I'm on the site. The php in the post does that. Whenever I'm on the a page, it also shows the "/" page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parse_url()` may help you:-

```
<li><p class="navbar-text"><a href="/" <?php if (parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'] =='/') {echo 'class="active"';} ?>>Forside</a></p></li>
<li><p class="navbar-text"><a href="/medlemmer" <?php if (parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'] =='/medlemmer') {echo 'class="active"';} ?>>Medlemmer</a></p></li>
<li><p class="navbar-text"><a href="/butik">Ansøg</a></p></li>
<li><p class="navbar-text"><a href="/" style="color:white;">Køb</a></p></li>
```

One example:-

```
<?php 
    $url = "http://localhost/";
    echo parse_url($url)['path'].'<br/>';
    $url = "http://localhost/medlemmer";
    echo parse_url($url)['path'];
 ?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/556980